# Error in drawing a fractal using basic recursion in python

Tags: python

So recently I was trying to complete my homework in the Python class I am currently taking, and I was attempting to draw a fractal pattern using recursion and basic python functions. I am running into the error in which my fractal keeps turning into the following amalgamation: [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i81I.png)

The desired result is, of course, a full fractal with the pattern you see on the far left branch.
Here is my code:

```
def drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx, cy, r, level):
    if level == 0:
        drawStellaFace(canvas, cx, cy, r)
    else:
        drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx, cy, r, level-1)
        drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx-cx//2, cy-cy//2, r//2, level-1)
        drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx+cx//2, cy-cy//2, r//2, level-1)
```

The drawStellaFace is just for the face you see in the pattern, and I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong? Could someone point out my error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left side works because the midpoint always cuts in half on it's way to zero. The right side is wrong because it cuts in half on it's way to infinity (depending on level count). In recursion, the child attributes are derived from the parent. For this code, the child centers should be determined in relation to the parent center.

Try this

```
def drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx, cy, r, level):
    if level == 0:
        drawStellaFace(canvas, cx, cy, r)
    else:
        drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx, cy, r, level-1)
        drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx-r, cy-r, r//2, level-1)
        drawStellaFractal(canvas, cx+r, cy-r, r//2, level-1)
```

Comment: Ah ok, so the issue was in part due to the recursion calling the child's previous cx, and also for the right side the expanding to infinity causing the skips? But isn't r also passed down each time and changed?(doesn't r//2 changes r?) So what is the difference between using cx//2 for say and r?

Comment: Considering only the right side, cs//2 = r is only true the first time.After that, cx moves to the right of the parent, so cx//2 actually spreads quickly to the right. By the third iteration, the rightmost 'ear' is off the screen. To clarify the issue, do the math manually for the right side and check the results.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was thinking you were talking about cx changing with each iteration, i.e, the cx = cx-cx//2, but I see now. Just a quick side questions, so the cx will remain the same in the end right? cause I'm not reassigning it at all? aka no doing cx = cx-cx//2

Comment: Te point of recursion is the child only sees what the parent sends it. In this case, the parent sends the child cs=cx+r and r=r/2. The child only sees the new cx and r. The child does not know how the parent calculated the values.Each level of recursion has it's own 'world' of values (cx,cy,r) unrelated to the level above.

Comment: Got it, that all makes sense now, really appreciate you taking the time to explain. (yes, I know I'm not supposed to say thanks according to comment rules)